# Spring: RestTemplate returns null object

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

With the below GET request:

```
ResponseEntity<String> entity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class );
entity.getBody();
```

returns a JSON String like this:

```
{"userRegistrations":[{"userRegistrationToken":"fb398972","userRegistrationTokenAlias":"87f15f8"}]}
```

But I want to make this work with an object not with a string. So with the code below I receive a UserRegistrations object with a null UserTokenResponse List

```
ResponseEntity<UserRegistrations> entity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, UserRegistrations.class );
entity.getBody();
```

And my domain class looks like this:

```
public class UserRegistrations {
    List<UserTokenResponse> userRegistrationList;
    //..getters and setters
}

public class UserTokenResponse {
   private String userRegistrationToken;
   private String userRegistrationTokenAlias;
   //getters and setters
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `getBody()` returns `null` in the second case? Are you using `Gson` as the `HttpMessageConverter` that parses your payload?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I dont parse manually anything. Its parsed automatically to the relevant object with this approach. I use this approach many other places too.

Comment: Well, the JSON object has a single attribute named `userRegistrations`, whereas your Java class has a single attribute named `userRegistrationList`. They don't match.

Comment: I'm not asking if you parsed anything manually. The `RestTemplate` registers a bunch of `HttpMessageConverter` objects automatically or through what you configured yourself. If you have Jackson on the classpath, it will register an `HttpMessageConverter` for Jackson. If you have Gson on the classpath, it will register a `HttpMessageConverter` for Gson. Which one is it?

Comment: Jackson would've complained about unknown members and thrown an exception. Gson would've just returned `null` if it couldn't make a conversion, so I assume you're using Gson. Unless there are other things you aren't showing us. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I use jackson

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks! could you create an answer so accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using Jackson, `RestTemplate` automatically registers a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` which configures the underlying `ObjectMapper` to ignore unknown properties.

The JSON object has a single attribute named `userRegistrations`, whereas your Java class has a single attribute named `userRegistrationList`. They don't match.

They need to match, or you need to add a `@JsonProperty` annotation of the attribute to make Jackson serialize/parse it as `userRegistrations`.

Comment: One would think that such a thing would be logged somewhere, or an exception thrown. But it just silently fails and returns `null`.

Comment: @milosmns - If you want to see an error if the value doesn't match than remove `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` from your POJO class.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your class property names doesn't match with the JSON property names coming in the response. For instance take the below example

```
    public class ScheduledCallbacks {

    private List<Callback> callbacks;

    public List<Callback> getCallbacks() {
        return callbacks;
    }

    public void setCallbacks(List<Callback> callbacks) {
        this.callbacks = callbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ScheduledCallbacks [callbacks=" + callbacks + "]";
    }
}
```

and if the response is the following way

```
{
  "scheduledCallbacks": [
    {
      "sessionId": "string",
      "customerNbr": "string",
      "topicName": "string",
      "desiredTime": "string",
      "callbackState": "string",
      "serviceName": "string",
      "expirationTime": "string",
      "programCode": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you get null response because the name scheduledCallbacks in the JSON response doesn't match with the name callbacks in class.

But if your class is as following

```
public class ScheduledCallbacks {

    private List<Callback> scheduledCallbacks;

    public List<Callback> getScheduledCallbacks() {
        return scheduledCallbacks;
    }
    public void setScheduledCallbacks(List<Callback> scheduledCallbacks) {
        this.scheduledCallbacks = scheduledCallbacks;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ScheduledCallbacks [scheduledCallbacks=" + scheduledCallbacks + "]";
    }
}
```

Then you get the expected response in response entity

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error and it was returning null too. The problem is over when Object.class is replaced with the name of the class we want to convert on the client side.

Like that:

`Token = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, Object.class);`

the problem was probably due to the fact that it is not directly compatible with the class we want to convert.